# How to display multiple lines of text in django admin?

Tags: django

I want to display text in multiple lines in django admin, but django ignore "\n".
This is what I've got:
[image: ss]
I just want to split this text in multiple lines, what is the best way to do it?

Comment: Django doesn't ignore \n; this is HTML, your browser does.

Comment: This isn't the case, django somehow don't allow new lines in cell.

Comment: Really, this is the browser doing it. `\n` has no meaning in HTML.

Comment: @Marksman You can write some JS to convert `\n` to `<br>` tag.

Comment: Page source for this line is "<td class="field-get_variants">ew2 1asda</td>". JS conversion could work, but I looked for a django-way solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i usually do it like this

```
from django.utils.html import linebreaks

class SomethingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = [..., 'admin_get_variants']

    def admin_get_variants(self, obj):
        return linebreaks(obj.get_variants)
    admin_get_variants.short_description = u'Get variants'
    admin_get_variants.admin_ordering_field = 'get_variants'
    admin_get_variants.allow_tags = True
```